# JDBI One-To-Many joins and mapping

Tags: java, sql, dropwizard, jdbi

I have following classes:

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Comment> comments;
    private List<Address> address;

    // getters/setters
}


public class Comment {

    private int id;
    private String comment;
    ...
    // getters/setters
}


public class Address {

    private int id;
    private String streetName;
    ...
    // getters/setters
}
```

And a user mapper:

```
public class UserMapper implements ResultSetMapper<User> {
    @Override
    public User map(int i, ResultSet resultSet, StatementContext statementContext) throws SQLException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
        user.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));

        // user.setComments 
        // user.setAddresses

        return user;
    }
}
```

Problem I'm trying to solve, is how to set comments and addresses to user. Also how would sql query look like for this?

Comment: The way I implemented this is by using transactions and several methods. Maybe not ideal, but essentially I am doing 3 queries for the objects and then merge them together. The transactional annotation fails the entire operations if one of my queries fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this [library](http://manikandan-k.github.io/jdbi_folder/). It automatically takes care of one to many mappings in JDBI.

Comment: Thank you. But, could you please show me how to use it on my example. I see that I have to use left joins in my sql which is cool, however, I'm confused about what do I have to map and and register in order to make it work.